# Numbers into currency format - char value has incorrect syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a row with > 2 numbers:

```
Type       DollarValue 
 2          1000000; 2000000
```

I want to get these into format:

```
Type       DollarValue 
 2          1,000,000; 2,000,000
```

I have tried using the convert e.g:

```
('$' + convert(nvarchar(29),convert(money,DollarValue),1))
```

but I am getting the below alert:

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

I believe this is because of the ';' inbetween the numbers?

Comment: `1000000, 2000000` isn't a proper dollar value. The convert doesn't expect a comma separated list of multiple dollar values. You might be able to use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If you are using a programming environment to call SQL, it might be easier to do that work there.

Comment: What's your sqlserver version?

Comment: Yes you can overcome this obstacle. In fact it is quite simple. You do it by normalizing your data and not storing multiple values in a single tuple. Your current design violates 1NF which is why you are struggling with this. Fix your design and then leave the formatting to the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2017 or a newer version, you could try this:

use `STRING_SPLIT` function to split by `;`, then use  `Format` function make your expect format. then combine data by `string_agg` function.

**Test DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   Type int,
   DollarValue varchar(100)
);
insert into t values (2,'1000000; 2000000;3000000');
```

**Query**

```
select 
    Type, string_agg(val, ';') as DollarValue 
from
    (select
         t.Type, 
         Format(Cast(value As Int), '###,000') val
     from
         T
     cross apply 
         STRING_SPLIT (t.DollarValue , ';' )) t1
group by 
   Type
```

**[Results]**:

```
| Type |                   DollarValue |
|------|-------------------------------|
|    2 | 1,000,000;2,000,000;3,000,000 |
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3a2f2/1